# float right не работает

Tags: css

Всем привет, простейший код - а уже не работает float right элемента toplineю
Работаю с Mozilla firefox 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Future site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class = "top_header">
        <div class = "header_topline">
            <div class = "container">
                <div class = "col-md-12">
                    <div class = "row">
                        <div class = "header_logo">
                            <img src = "img/ETS.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "header_menue">
                            qw
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </header>   

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.header_topline {
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.header_menue {
    width: 85%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: там в конце float: right; я здесь опечатался

Answer (score 0):

`float` работает, вам нужно изменить местами `header_logo` и `header_menue`

```css
.header_topline {
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.header_menue {
    width: 85%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Future site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="top_header">
        <div class="header_topline">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="header_menue">
                            qw
                        </div>
                        <div class="header_logo">
                            <img src="img/ETS.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я так и сделал , но лого просто уехал вправо, а header_menue прилип влево, то есть сам float : right опять никак не реагирует . Может ли быть проблема в том , что у меня пробник саблайма? Unregistered version?